# Colour transition in d3 always starting with black

Tags: d3.js

I have made a small example showing the problem: http://bl.ocks.org/nvcleemp/df035fc9c14f9955d4f0

When you click any of the two links, then you see a small animation which changes the background colour. This animation always starts from black, while I want it to start at the current colour. This is just a small example, in the real problem there are many more links that have to change colour, and I don't 'know' which is the correct starting colour. (I can always look it up, but I cannot hard-code it into the function)

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to have a transition start from a well-known state is to set that state yourself. In your case, set the background colour at the beginning:

```
d3.select("#test1").style("background", notSelectedColor);
d3.select("#test2").style("background", notSelectedColor);
```

Complete demo [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/f1a023777d7fa4439290).

Comment: For me that demo still has the colours starting at black during the transition. Is this not the case for you? If so, then we are dealing with a browser-specific problem.

Comment: Works fine for me on Opera and Chrome.

Comment: Yep, for me as well, but Firefox always starts from black.

Comment: Hmm, same here. Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution for this in Firefox?